# What does a superscript 'r' in IPA mean?

Tags: pronunciation

I am aware of the pronunciation of the IPA /ɔː/ and /ɔːr/.

Cambridge dictionary gives this IPA. What does the superscript 'r' pointed out by red arrow mean?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the IPA is a standard way of writing down pronunciation, there's some wiggle room for different linguists to use it in subtly different ways.  You'll notice that each dictionary has its own conventions; some write the [DRESS vowel as /e/](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/dress_1), for example, while others [write it as /ɛ/](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/dress).  That doesn't mean those dictionaries disagree about how the vowel is pronounced, though!  They're just making different decisions about how to use the IPA to represent the same sounds.

Because each dictionary has its own conventions, the first thing you want to look for is a key to how *they're* transcribing things.  For Cambridge, you can find it here:

- [User guide to phonetics](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/help/phonetics.html)

And you'll notice when you look at this page that it explains how it uses the superscript <sup>r</sup>:

> linking r is pronounced only before a vowel in British English:
>   fɔː<sup>r</sup> + ˈæp.l ̩z = fɔːˈræp.l ̩z
>   four + apples = four apples

This convention isn't universal, though.  For example, the Longman Pronunciation Dictionary uses <sup>r</sup> only for *intrusive R*, not *linking R*.  You can see this in the LPD's transcription of *thawing*:

> [image: Transcription of thaw from the LPD]

In this example, the R is considered intrusive because there was no /r/ present in the word historically, which is why there is no ‹r› in the spelling of the word.  The LPD doesn't use superscript <sup>r</sup> to transcribe the linking R in *four*, though, writing /fɔː/ instead.

So as you can see, conventions differ from dictionary to dictionary, and the first thing you should check should be the key to symbols in the particular dictionary you're using, which will give you the answer above.